# Looking for a better algorithm (conditional rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

On my webapplication I use a json file to store my different routes, and I loop over an array inside this json file to create content, such navbar buttons.

The problem I face is that I would like to use a different icon for each value displayed from the json file, and I cannot store the icon component into the json file.

Here is my sample of code with the loop on the array contained in the json file

```
{props.buttons.button.map((button, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    {(button.isAuth === props.isAuth || button.isAuth === 3) && (
                        <>
                            <Link to={button.to} className="link">
                                <ListItem button>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <InputIcon />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary={button.label} />
                                </ListItem>
                            </Link>
                        </>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
```

Here is a sample of the json file

```
{
    "button": [
        {
            "label": "Home",
            "isAuth": 3,
            "to": "/"
        },
        {
            "label": "About",
            "isAuth": 3,
            "to": "/about"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, for each data on my json file, always the same icon component is displayed : `<InputIcon />`.

How can I display a different icon component for each data from the json file (such as `<HomeIcon />` for the home button, `<LogInIcon />` for the login one, ...) without using and `if/else`

Thanks

Comment: one possible solution: store the icon name in string format in json, then create a map in component with key-value pair like this: `const IconMap = { 'HomeIcon': HomeIcon, 'LoginIcon': LoginIcon }`, then use the json string value to render the correct icon with help of map.

Comment: ^^^^  this is the way i would probably do it (Mayank's answer). To add to it, in the rendering component (wherever the buttons are imported into) you will need to also import all the possible icon components of course, but to keep the render clean, you can create a function `determineIcon` which uses a `switch` statement to evaluate the value of each objects icon property,  and returns the proper icon component, then in your render you can call that function (rather than putting a clunky, long conditional in the render itself)

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can structure the `<InputIcon />` component to accept a `prop` and pass the label to this component.